# Переустановка MarioDB SSH CentOs7

Tags: mariadb

Переустанавливал mariabd, после переустановки не запускается
Пытаюсь запустить, получаю ошибку:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mariadb.service
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

При проверке статуса  **service mariadb status** получаю

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status mariadb.service

● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.25 database server

   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)

  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-10-29 08:13:23 MSK; 33s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/

  Process: 13380 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

  Process: 13294 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

  Process: 13291 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 Main PID: 13380 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu mysqld[13380]: 2020-10-29  8:13:23 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu mysqld[13380]: 2020-10-29  8:13:23 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu mysqld[13380]: 2020-10-29  8:13:23 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu mysqld[13380]: 2020-10-29  8:13:23 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu mysqld[13380]: 2020-10-29  8:13:23 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu mysqld[13380]: 2020-10-29  8:13:23 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.25 database server.

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.

Oct 29 08:13:23 tdnu systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

Кто нибудь помогите

Comment: При запуске mysqld -u root
выдает InnoDB: Invalid flags 0x4800 in ./ibdata1

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/379714/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb-mysql-ubuntu вдруг поможет